# What is the semantic meaning of ∈?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this assignment homework in an intro to discrete mathematics class, and I'm talking a class mate about a statement I wrote, and how he interprets such a statement.

$$ 11x + 3 = 10 \in \mathbb{Z}_{18} $$

My friend thinks that this means that the literal untouched equation of the left of $\in$ is inside the set, as in  $\{11x + 3 = 10, 0, 1, 2, \cdots\}$

I think that equations means $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}_{18}$ such that $11x + 3 = 10$

The original homework question is:

[image]

Which is why I used the previous form, does the statement change because I've dropped the word "solve" or replaced "in" with "$\in$" (he is very adamant that these are not synonyms).

How should I read my original equation? Should I avoid this form?

Comment: $\in$ have multiple meanings. Denying all but one of them would be unreasonable.

Comment: The statement you wrote means “$11x + 3$ is equal to $10$, which is an element of $\mathbb Z_{18}$”. The homework problem, however, is asking you to find $x \in \mathbb Z_{18}$ such that $11\cdot x + 3 = 10$. (Here $+$ and $\cdot$ are the addition and multiplication operations associated with $\mathbb Z_{18}$.)

Comment: Originally, the epsilon is an abbreviation for  the verb " to be" ( in Greek) ; belonging to a set S means to be an S.

Answer (score 2):

I think that stating the problem in another way will make it clearer:

> In $\Bbb Z_{18}$, solve the equation $11x+3=10$.

So, the “in” here is telling you to work in the ring $\Bbb Z_{18}$. It has nothing to do with a thing being an element of a set.

Comment: "work in" just means that all terms are elements of the set doesn't it?
I'm just confused if ∈ means we should "pattern match" the term wise, or if the it's not really used is this form and should avoid that syntax.

Comment: It's a little more than that. It also means that the operation $+$ is the one from $\Bbb Z_{18}$.

Comment: Not to mention, the implicit multiplication in $11 x$.